# Authenticated SMTP PHP code

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, email, smtp-auth

I'm new in coding in PHP and I've been trying to figure out how to send contact form data through a SMTP authenticated PHP script. So far, it's been very frustating and I couldn't do it.

I have this bootstrap form on an HTML page and I don't know how to create the contact.php script to send it with SMTP authenticated.

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="contato.php" role="form">
    <div class="messages"></div>
        <div class="controls">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_name">Nome:</label>
                    <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Qual o seu nome?" required="required" data-error="Você precisa informar seu nome.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_email">Email:</label>
                    <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Qual o seu e-mail?" required="required" data-error="Insira um e-mail válido.">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="form_phone">Fone:</label>
                    <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Qual o seu telefone?">
                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
                    `enter code here`</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="form_message">Mensagem:</label>
                            <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Mensagem para o Rancho" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Qual a sua mensagem?"></textarea>
                            <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                        </div>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Enviar">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**My contato.php**

```
<?php


require_once('class.phpmailer.php');

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.ranchopremier.com.br";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'contato@ranchopremier.com.br';
$mail->Password = 'mypass';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

$mail->From = "contato@ranchopremier.com.br";
$mail->Sender = "contato@ranchopremier.com.br";
$mail->FromName = "Locaweb";

$mail->AddAddress('contato@ranchopremier.com.br', 'Teste Locaweb');
$mail->AddAddress('id@live.com');

$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject  = "CONTATO DO SITE";
$mail->Body = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em HTML!;
$mail->AltBody = 'Este é o corpo da mensagem de teste, em Texto Plano! \r\n;

$enviado = $mail->Send();

$mail->ClearAllRecipients();
$mail->ClearAttachments();

if ($enviado) {
echo "E-mail enviado com sucesso!";
} else {
echo "Não foi possível enviar o e-mail.";
echo "Informações do erro:" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}

?>
```

If anyone would like to help I will appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: install: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer read its documentation, test it, come back if you have issues

Comment: Hi nogad. I installed it and now I'm receiving e-mails, but the form data is coming. Take a look below on the codes I've been using.

Comment: edit the question with the new code, and explain the issue there

Comment: all your form values will be in the `$_POST` array ie `$_POST['phone'']`

Comment: Nogad, thanks for your help. I'm starting to get it. Can I put the POST array in the contato.php inside the $mail -> Body or should I create another PHP page?